# How to render a Web User Control into a PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, render, placeholder

Can someone help me to create my custom web user control to be render into a placeholder dynamically?

I just created a web user control which does not have code in the server side just design in the aspx because all the functionallity is client-side.

**Web Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebControlDemo.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project1.Web.UI.WebControlDemo" %>
<div>
Blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

**In another page**

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   WebControlDemo wcd = new WebControlDemo();
   this.placeHolder1.Controls.Add(wcd);
}
```

But I can't see anything. So what so I need to add that can finally becomes rendered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't create User controls manually in code. You should use [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method from Page object. Then it will initialize it correctly. Like this

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   WebControlDemo wcd = this.LoadControl("~/SomePath/WebControlDemo.ascx") as WebControlDemo;
   this.placeHolder1.Controls.Add(wcd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but there's a way to do the initialization inside the same control in order to add it directly in the placeholder?

Comment: What do you mean by initialization? User controls also have Page_Load method, so you can make initialization in it.

Comment: I mean inside the same control Init event do the same thing LoadControl in order to avoid in the main page to expose the control and use the placeHolder.Controls.Add(new WebControlDemo()) directly.

Comment: Yes, you can load this control in Init and add it later in Button1_Click. Or as another solution, you can place it aspx markup into placeholder, but set Visible=false. And then when you need to display it, you can just switch Visible to True. In that case you don't need to create it manually